# At exporting table to excel, double numbers are changed as date type

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel

I have in table column, his type is decimal and in him is stored numbers like this

```
2.3
2.0
3.3
4.2
```

I want export this table in excel, I export table as csv file.

But when open csv file in excel, data like this `4.2`  displayed as `04.02.2013`

I need that `4.2` displayed as `4.2` in excel, how to make this?

Comment: Best practice is to NEVER open CSV files in Excel. You can either ***import*** data in the file, or force Excel to go through the Text Import wizard by changing the file extension to TXT.

Answer (score 0):

Don't double-click on the .csv file but open Excel and Data > Get External Data - From Text. Choose the .csv file and click Import. Select Delimited and click Next. Select Comma etc as necessary and click Next. At this point ensure that Column data format is *not* Date.